# ASP.Net Core Identity - Unable to stay logged in for more than 20 mintues - IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

After deploying an ASP.Net Core app using Identity to Windows 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5) I cannot stay logged in after about 20 minutes of inactivity. I'm only using simple username / password authentication, no third party stuff.

This is not an issue on my Dev machine running VS 2017.

AccountController.cs

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");
                return View("Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Any help kindly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is my ConfigureServices method in it's entirety. It has an authorization policy which could be relevant.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("UserOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("User"));
            options.AddPolicy("InstructorOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("Instructor"));
            options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
            options.AddPolicy("SystemManagerOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("Manager"));

        });

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                             .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        // Configure Identity
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(240);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(15);
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOff";
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;



        });

        var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettings);

        // Inject the ability to get current user
        services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        // Inject the User access class
        services.AddTransient<UserResolverService>();


    }
```

Here is a screenshot of Chrome Dev Tools showing the response/request cookie. The Login page seems to send the correct cookie with a an expiration 15 days into the future. Subsequent pages are called using this cookie.

[image: Login page redirect]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to see any expire date in Chrome Debugger Tool ? What it display ?

Comment: Yes. The Expire date is show in the initial response cookie. It shows login date + 15 days as it should. (See my edit of the orginal post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some very strange reason I'm not seeing this problem anymore.

The only change I made to either config or code was configuring the IIS version log to enable cs(Cookie).

Thank for your assistance @Rohith Rajan

Answer (score 1):

**_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync** creates a cookie like this

`Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=<cookie value>; expires=Fri, 14 Jul 2017 02:59:56 GMT; path=/; httponly`

Next time when you make a request it should send this cookie if it is within the expires timestamp.Which will happen in your case

do you have some custom Authorize [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies) written ? Also in your application,Are you storing in anything in session and or any global variable and then checking it on login ?

> 20 minutes is the default IdleTimeout of IIS.Whenever any worker
>   process is idle for more than 20 minutes,IIS shuts the process down
>   .When the next request comes it automatically bring the worker process
>   up.You can [configure](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx) a higher timeout or an infinite timeout for the application pool

Comment: Thanks @Rohith Rajan. I do have an authorize policy. I added my ConfigureServices method to the orginal post along with a screenshot of the cookie in the Chrome Dev Tools. I'm not storing anything in the session or using any global var that I'm checking on login.

Comment: Since ti works locally , I just want to double check if the expires is being stripped of by something in between .Could you enable [Cookie (cs(Cookie))](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/iis-docs/blob/master/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis.md#to-select-w3c-fields-to-log-by-using-the-ui) logging in IIS and check if expires is being send from IIS

Comment: The log with the cs option does not display expiry information. After looking a more closely at the debug info from Chrome I see that I get issued with a cookie with correct expire info (see screenshot). 
I have done some more (time consuming) testing. I did a refresh after an hour of no activity I get a new cookie with a new expire time. The sliding expiration seems to work ok.
I see that the cookie generation is the same on the dev machine. I’m not sure why I’m now able to stay logged in for 60 minutes. No changes have been made. Will report back after trying 2 hours of inactivity.